# Grouping multiple count queries on same table by time

Tags: mysql, sql, time, group-by, count

I have a query in which I need 3 columns, along with an additional ‘Time’ Column, what I need to do is run each of the count queries and match them to the time associated, however whats happening is the query is returning a sum of the counts and adding them to each time. See below.
[image]

what should be happening is I get a list like so:

[image]

I know its the way I'm grouping at the end but I can't seem to group within the counts, anyone have any ideas?

```
SELECT
case 
when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started) = 0 ) then '12am'
when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started) < 12) then concat(extract(HOUR FROM e.started), 'am') 
when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started) = 12) then '12pm'
when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started) > 12) then concat( ( extract(HOUR FROM e.started) -12 ), 'pm') 
end  AS "Time", 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM eventinfo e
    join tickets o on e.ticket_id = o.id
    where e.created > '2018-02-20 00:00:00' and e.created < '2018-02-21 00:00:00'
        and o.stagename = ’Stage3'
) AS 'Column1',
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM eventinfo e
    join tickets o on e.ticket_id = o.id
    where e.created > '2018-02-20 00:00:00' and e.created < '2018-02-21 00:00:00'
    and o.stagename = ’Stage2'

) AS 'Column2',
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM eventinfo e
    join tickets o on e.ticket_id = o.id
    where e.created > '2018-02-20 00:00:00' and e.created < '2018-02-21 00:00:00'
    and o.stagename = ’Stage1'
) AS 'Column3'
FROM eventinfo e
group by extract(hour from e.started)
```

EDIT: 
If I query the time from within each count query, I get the error: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

```
    SELECT
(
    SELECT 
    case 
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) = 0 ) then '12am'
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) < 12) then concat(extract(HOUR FROM e.started_at), 'am') 
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) = 12) then '12pm'
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) > 12) then concat( ( extract(HOUR FROM e.started_at) -12 ), 'pm') 
    end  AS "Time", 
    COUNT(*)
    FROM events e
    join operations o on e.operation_id = o.id
where e.created_at > '2018-02-20 00:00:00' and e.created_at < '2018-02-21 00:00:00'
    and o.stagename = ’Stage1'
) AS 'Column1',
(
    SELECT 
    case 
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) = 0 ) then '12am'
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) < 12) then concat(extract(HOUR FROM e.started_at), 'am') 
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) = 12) then '12pm'
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) > 12) then concat( ( extract(HOUR FROM e.started_at) -12 ), 'pm') 
    end  AS "Time", 
    COUNT(*)
    FROM events e
    join operations o on e.operation_id = o.id
where e.created_at > '2018-02-20 00:00:00' and e.created_at < '2018-02-21 00:00:00'
    and o.stagename = ’Stage2'

) AS 'Column2',
(
    SELECT 
    case 
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) = 0 ) then '12am'
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) < 12) then concat(extract(HOUR FROM e.started_at), 'am') 
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) = 12) then '12pm'
    when ( extract( HOUR FROM e.started_at) > 12) then concat( ( extract(HOUR FROM e.started_at) -12 ), 'pm') 
    end  AS "Time", 
    COUNT(*)
    FROM events e
    join operations o on e.operation_id = o.id
    where e.created_at > '2018-02-20 00:00:00' and e.created_at < '2018-02-21 00:00:00'
    and o.stagename = ’Stage3'
) AS 'Column3'
```

Comment: PLEASE TAG YOUR DBMS in order to get a proper answer

Comment: Sorry @iSR5 , its mysql

Comment: I think you should revise your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You querying same sources too many times. All can be done in one run. For more specific answer please specify RDBMS you are using and some more info on desired output, as the one you provided clearly not the result of the query.

Try this:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(e.started, "%h"), TIME_FORMAT(e.started, "%p")) AS "Time", 

sum(case when  o.stagename = 'Stage3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Column1',
sum(case when  o.stagename = 'Stage2' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Column2',
sum(case when  o.stagename = 'Stage1' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Column3'

FROM eventinfo e
    join tickets o on e.ticket_id = o.id

group by extract(hour from e.started)
```

Comment: that works great thank you! Just a quick question, if I was to find the difference between 2 and have that as another column, how would I go about it? I appreciate the help!

Comment: If I understood correctly, you simply need to add new columns, like 'Column1' - 'Column2' as col_1_2_diff.

Comment: @Alex you could replace the first `CASE` with this `CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(e.started, "%h"), TIME_FORMAT(e.started, "%p"))  AS "Time"` This should give the same output except it's a shorter method.